# absolute view position gravity stay with parent of parent instead of parent

Tags: android, layout-gravity

Can I set the blue view in the center of the black layout Knowing that the black layout is it's parent of parent

like in the image

[center parent of parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1baZ.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change things around a bit, you can't put a view relative to a parent's parent.

You need a RelativeLayout as the root layout, and then you place the blue line centered vertically. Then you would place the red LinearLayouts above and below the blue layout. Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/blue_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#ff0000ff" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/above"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/blue_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/below"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/blue_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped me.